# Пунктуация: запятая, запятая и тире; другие знаки?

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, с пунктуацией в таком предложении:

> Прошу сообщить, какие фрукты вы предпочитаете(?) яблоки или груши.

Интересует знак препинания после слова «предпочитаете». Что здесь должно быть: запятая, двоеточие, тире или запятая-тире? Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Это тот случай, когда автор достаточно свободен в выборе знака. Можно выбрать любой. Они выражают оттенки речи.

**Запятая** характерна для передачи разговорной речи. Часто её допустимо использовать и вместо длинного тире, и вместо двоеточия. Но в "серьёзных" текстах так лучше не писать.

**Двоеточие** делает акцент на возможности выбора, мол, скажите, мне точно нужно знать, яблоки или груши вы предпочитаете. То есть из этих двух.

**Длинное тире** придаёт последним двум словам уточняющее звучание. То есть сам вопрос это "какие фрукты вы предпочитаете", потом пауза, мы даём слушателю задуматься, а потом как бы подсказываем: "Яблоки или груши", чтобы ему было проще ответить. Плюс, при постановке длинного тире понадобится ещё одна закрывающая запятая для оборота "какие", так что будет и тире, и запятая.

В Вашем случае, на мой взгляд, исходя из вышесказанного, лучше всего выбрать *двоеточие.*

Также возможен вариант, где яблоки и груши берутся в *скобки*.

Comment: В р. яз. нет "длинного" тире. Как и "короткого".

Comment: @Galina Avanesova вы прекрасно знаете, что я имею в виду, не вводите людей в заблуждение своими упрощениями https://orfogrammka.ru/типографика/различие_тире_и_дефиса/, и без этого хватает грамотеев, пишущих всё через дефисы и «n-dash».

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант:

***Прошу сообщить: какие фрукты вы предпочитаете — яблоки или груши?***

Answer (score 1):

Мне очень стыдно, но сегодня я решила, что **ответ надо исправить**: **однородные члены *яблоки или груши* входят в придаточное.** [Ср. *Прошу сообщить, какие фрукты - яблоки или груши - вы предпочитаете*.]

***Прошу сообщить, какие фрукты вы предпочитаете — яблоки или груши.***

Придаточное предложение *какие фрукты вы предпочитаете - яблоки или груши*.

Перед однородными членами *яблоки или груши* ставим тире.

[Обобщающие слова при ОЧ](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=103#pp103)  **Если однородные члены предложения носят характер приложения или уточнения, то после обобщающего слова вместо двоеточия может ставиться тире**: *Алый свет нежно заливал окрестности — ветряную мельницу, шиферные крыши машинно-тракторной станции, элеваторы (Кат.); Легенды и сказки любят все — дети и взрослые.*

[Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=118#pp118)   ***Дорога раздваивается, и неизвестно, куда идти дальше — прямо или налево.***

Answer (score 0):

1) В таком предложении ставится  двоеточие (или тире), в устной речи делается предупредительная пауза.

***Прошу сообщить, какие фрукты вы предпочитаете: яблоки или груши.***

2) Сравнить: Какие фрукты вы предпочитаете, **яблоки или груши**?

Постановка запятой связана с тем, что **одиночный союз ИЛИ** соединяет однородные члены в одну фразу,  поэтому в "коротком варианте" не требуются такие сильные знаки, как двоеточие или тире. Предупредительной паузы нет.

3) Также допускается постановка **вопросительного знака** в косвенной речи.

***Прошу сообщить, какие фрукты вы предпочитаете: яблоки или груши?***

....если косвенный вопрос содержит сильно выраженную вопросительную интонацию, в конце сложноподчиненного предложения ставится вопросительный знак: Скажите, пожалуйста, что это за огни? (Л. Т.); Я спросил, как же он стал отшельником? (М. Г.) http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=88#pp88